# How to change vertically tabbed content panel into responsive collapsible with media queries and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am attempting to build a content navigation pattern that uses vertically stacked tabs to toggle the display of hidden content panels next to the tabs. At smaller widths, this pattern breaks.

Heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrotton/xCeX8/1/

It is somewhat responsive...but lets say I have 12 tabs and the length of their labels range from "Nursing" to "Architecture, Design, and Construction". This breaks when the screen gets below 500px or so.

I could:

```
.contextNav { width: 100%; }
ul.checklist-select li { display:inline-block; }
```

..it works but it not ideal when you have more than a few tabs. 
I would rather hide the tab menu and change the panels into collapsibles with clickable h2's. It's also important that the pattern is screen-reader-accessible but I haven't made it that far yet.

Any ideas on how I could do this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have a look at jQuery UI accordion.  If I follow your question it may be just what you're looking for

Comment: I edited my question because an accordion isn't really what I'm looking for. The height of the panels range from 400-1200px and I would like all of them to be collapsed by default.

Comment: Understandable. However, both of those things can be accomplished with the jQuery accordion by setting collapsible : true, active : false, autoHeight : false.  Not trying to talk you into it, just sayin'...:)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts

Here's a few ideas...

Also I would say with what you have at the moment, floating that menu to the right on the mobile version isn't going to work. at the mobile size, those nav items should be 100% width, and the nav should be above the content, or should be another "slide panel".

Jquery mobile also has some very useful, very common design patterns built right in:

http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: Yeah, those layouts are slick. I'm not that familiar with Foundation, but I'm interested enough to try it out.